# Why won't the CSS effects show up on the webpage?

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to add CSS effects to a webpage via a master CSS file, but the effects of the CSS code that I expect to see aren't displayed when I refresh my webpage.

The HTML code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% block styles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}">
{% endblock %}

<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h2>Login or Sign-up for free to get started!</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

The base.html code

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="httpss://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/master.css' %}">


</head>


<body>

<header>
    {% include "header.html" %}
</header>
    <div class="container mycontent">
      {% block content %}

      {% endblock %}

    </div>

    <footer>
    <div class="container">
        {% include "footer.html" %}
    </div>
</footer>



<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>



</body>
<script src="{% static "js/master.js"%}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</html>
```

The CSS code

```
h1, h2 {
color: orange;
}
```

I expect the text in the h1 and h2 tags to be orange, but they're black right now.

Comment: Post `base.html`. Does `master.css` file loads?

Comment: @Gasanov I added the base.html code, and no, the master.css file doesn't load

Comment: If your statics are not loading, read about [managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)

Comment: Try adding `{% load static %}` to top of your web page html.